# Type error using Enumerable.Where

Tags: c#, lambda, html-agility-pack

I am working on a project to retrieve some data from a website. To complete the job, I decided to utilize the HtmlAgilityPack.

Everything is working fine except an issue I am facing related to lambda expressions. The error I am receiving is

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to 'bool'

```
var page = RetrievePage(url); //retrieve page
var document = GetDocument(page); //get the document
var optionNodes = document.Result.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("???"); //Select nodes based on selector

//remove empty lines
var filteredNodes = optionNodes[0].ChildNodes.Where(n => n.InnerText.Trim() != string.Empty);

using (var nodes = filteredNodes.GetEnumerator())
{
   while (nodes.MoveNext())
   {
      //error
      var children = nodes.Current.ChildNodes.Where(c => c.Attributes.Where(t => t.Value == "???"));
   }
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: This part of the LINQ query will return an IEnumerable [c.Attributes.Where(t => t.Value == "???")] and you are passing it to the previous where operator, and my guess is that, this is where the conversion is failing. (you may need to revist the first where condition)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inner where will return rows. The outer where can only be an expression which has a boolean. So you have to change this:

```
var children = nodes.Current.ChildNodes
               .Where(c => c.Attributes.Where(t => t.Value == "???"));
```

To this:

```
var children = nodes.Current.ChildNodes
              .Where(c => c.Attributes.Any(t => t.Value == "???"));
```

Or this:

```
var children = nodes.Current.ChildNodes
               .Where(c => c.Attributes.All(t => t.Value == "???"));
```

Or this:

```
var children = nodes.Current.ChildNodes
               .Where(c => c.Attributes.Where(t => t.Value == "???").Count()>0);
```

Reference:

- [Enumerable.Any Method (IEnumerable, Func)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534972%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Enumerable.All Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)